# MikTex 2.9 Package Repository woes

Tags: packages, miktex, installing

After trying (unsuccessfully) to install the `mathtools` package it now seems my entire package manager is broken. I can no longer get to a point where  I can select a mirror from the list. Automatic downloads and install no longer works and I can't seem to poke any buttons to get back to my previous state.

[image]

I now just get errors after clicking OK:

[image]

Comment: recent days the MikTeX server is not working. be patient for some days.

Comment: MikTeX servers are again on!

Comment: Oh thank God, I'd thought I'd horked up my MikTex for sure...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the MiKTeX server was off line for a short time ...